# How can I disable clipboard and task-switching operations while my program or Web site is active?

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, html

Is it possible to create a website or an application for windows machine(desktop) which can stay focused or precisely stay open until user submits or complete a given task.

For example,
My XXX app/website is open.I want the user to fill some text.The thing I want is that,
the user should NOT BE ABLE to perform following

1. ctrl+c or ctrl+v all those shortcuts
2. ctrl+alt+del (i guess this impossible to do on a website)
3. ctrl+shift+Esc

In simple words I don't want user to copy text from a text file,I don't want user to minimize this XXX app/website and switch to Explorer or notepad or something else.

I don't think website can do all this can a windows desktop application do this?

Comment: **NO**, you can not do that from a website. And I am very glad you can not. Also, Control-Alt-Delete is *meant* not to be able to be captured by a normal program as a security feature (so that you know that the resulting prompt could only be from Windows itself)

Comment: No, you can't do that with a website. You *may* (I don't know for sure) be able to do what you need with an application, however. You don't necessarily need to prevent them copying text from another application, you may be able to get away with only preventing them from pasting to your application.

Comment: I know it is usurp..I want to create a XX thing which will allow user to solve some question but should not copy answers from their hard drive...is it possible to do anthing close to it....or any other way to do so?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: the thing is user can just read text from notepad and just type in my app...I don't want that.

Comment: I WANT USER TO FILL ANSWER SHEET ON COMP BUT THEY CAN EASILY TAKE ANSWERS FROM THEIR HARD DRIVE...

IS THERE ANY WAY???????????

Comment: @Pointer: perhaps you could instead warn the user that they should not leave your application during the question, then detect if they do and treat the transgression appropriately.

Comment: What if the user has another computer handy?

Comment: @Pointer: all caps is typically read as shouting.  You should perhaps be mindful of how you appear to others reading the site who have no reason or requirement to help you.

Comment: @Pointer: They could also easily take answers from a piece of paper.  How will you stop that?

Comment: @DanPuzey: see copying from a piece of paper is old and classic way it can not be stoped unless you keep a supervisor.so consider a supervisor in the room with students.

Comment: If you have a supervisor in the room, they can also watch for students using other applications.  Windows is explicitly designed so that you *cannot* stop people getting to the task manager.  That said: I guess that a custom Windows Shell might be able to override this; I'm not sure.  But now you're getting into rewriting Windows Explorer...

Comment: @Pointy : no there can be a supervisor for that

Comment: @DanPuzey : no supervisor won't be able to look at everyone's computer and students have their own laptops and students are more smart than supervisor...this is the condition here in india...bad luck..

Comment: @DanPuzey : there has to be some way...may be not possible with an app but may be possible with something else.i don't know?

Comment: No, @Pointer, this is what everyone's telling you: Windows is explicitly designed to *prevent* what you are trying to do.  *It is not possible with Windows.*

Comment: @DanPuzey : ok..so..but answer given by Dampsquid down there holds some attention..I havn't tried it cause i'm not on a windows machine now.

Comment: First thing this made me think of was that god-awful Metropolitan Police ransomware. Stuff like this shouldn't be done for a reason.

Comment: It *is* possible, I've seen it firsthand, but I don't know how it was done and I don't particularly want to.

Comment: To be honest, you are all a bit quick to judge from the question alone. There are valid applications where stuff like this is useful or even mandatory: cashpoints, school assignments, kiosk apps in production lines, ...

Comment: @phresnel - we were quick to judge because the question did not contain important, relevant information.  The phrase 'kiosk app' would have prevented all the aggro.  The point is that such apps as you mention are run on secure hardware, often with special human-interfaces, eg. keypads, touchscreens, not a standard PC keyboard.  The desire of the OP can certainly be met, (on XP anyway, as anyone who has used a hotel lobby pay-per-minute internet kiosk will know), but I'm not sure how it's done - it's probably non-trivial.

Comment: i landed on this page http://www.sitekiosk.com/SiteKiosk/Default.aspx
they says "Protect your public PCs and prevent user access to the operating system"

Comment: now i know either i can buy this software or create one for myself..:)

but i don't know how to create those? are they like windows app written in low-programming languages or c++ or something...like how they create such kiosk software which runs on windows machine and converts it into a kiosk..

Comment: Congratulations, you have signed up for [a game of walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx). *No one wins this game.*

Answer (score 2):

Windows desktop application **must not be able** to do what you are asking either. In essence you are hoping to usurp the control of the user's computer... This will never be allowed by any reasonable OS or a web browser

Comment: I know it is usurp..I want to create a XX thing which will allow user to solve some question but should not copy answers from their hard drive...u getting it?

Comment: Sounds as if all you need is to prevent from pasting text, that is possible.

Comment: @Dr.Molle : ya preventing from pasting text is possible but user can just read it from other editor and can just type in my app.How do i prevent that?

Comment: I WANT USER TO FILL ANSWER SHEET ON COMP BUT THEY CAN EASILY TAKE ANSWERS FROM THEIR HARD DRIVE... IS THERE ANY WAY???????????


THERE HAS TO BE SOME WAY

Comment: Of course there's a way, just remove the hard drive and give it a good bashing.

Comment: Even if you were able to block the user, he could still print out the information before opening your app and then type it from paper ;)

Comment: .. or they could just read it from their iPhone browser, or tablet file.  There is a reason that most examinations are still done on paper.

Comment: @C.Stoll : let him do that...it's ok to read before you open the app..
havn't you read the book one more last time just entering exam hall?
may be not but i'm ok with that..

Comment: If it's examinations you're aiming at, use hardware protection - keyboards without Alt, secure casing, no ports ie a kiosk-type computer.  That, and appropriate security policy should be OK.  Oh, and don't shout - it just pisses people off and you get the kind of replies you then deserve.

Comment: @Pointer: So what's the difference between "open answer file, print it out, then open app" and "open answer file, then open app - and switch to the already open file" (the last version would even save me some paper)?

Comment: @C.Stoll : no man not like that...once you open the app there is no way back(sounds scary) until you submit the app

Comment: Let's try again: For you it's ok if I open the file with the answer(s), print it out and then open your app and type in the answer from the print. But it's not ok if I open the answer file, leave it in the background and then open your app and task-switch back to the file to memorize the answer to type in. So what's the difference? (I used the same help, only I didn't waste any paper in the second case). PS: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @C.Stoll It's turtles all the way down!

Comment: @Woody +1 just for the Prachett reference:)

Answer (score 1):

You can never disable Ctrl-Alt-Delete in a Windows computer. The key combination is intercepted by the Windows kernel, and you will not even get a chance to see it in your javascript or desktop application. You can **attempt** to write a driver that gets the key before the kernel gets at it, but I'm not sure if that's actually doable either. Either way that's out of the scope of a desktop application.

The other shortcuts you've listed can be captured.

Comment: I would never install, or would instantly remove, any app that prevented access to the task manager.  Unless you are an anonymous malware writer, you would leave yourself open to lawsuits from any client whose machine became infected while they had no access to the TM.

Comment: @MartinJames : please read the description i have given in CAPS..I am not trying make any malware.

Comment: Maybe not, but I know this how?  The thing is, you have not given much detail of of how your app is to be used.  I would be happy sitting an an exam kiosk, typing answers into a secure PC with policy set to prevent running anything I shouldn't, no ports and perhaps a keyboard with no Alt key so I cannot even try to access the Task Manager.  In my office, I would not be so happy at all.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on other answers/comments:

1. Disabling copy and paste *within your own application* is relatively trivial.  You can't stop the user from copying and pasting in other applications, though.  What you mean by "all those shortcuts" is unclear, but in general a "Ctrl-Something" shortcut is defined by the application and so you can override it.
2. Disabling Ctrl-Alt-Del is never possible from a website *or* a Windows application.  This is by design.
3. Ctrl-Shift-Esc is conceivably overrideable by an application, but an initial experiment with a WPF app suggests that this needs to be handled at a lower level than .NET easily exposes.

Comment: I WANT USER TO FILL ANSWER SHEET ON COMP BUT THEY CAN EASILY TAKE ANSWERS FROM THEIR HARD DRIVE... 
IS THERE ANY WAY??????????? THERE HAS TO SOME WAY

Comment: @POINTER: I DON'T AGREE TO BLINDLY ASSUME YOU ARE DOING SOMETHING WRONG WITH YOUR APP, BUT I DON'T THINK ALL CAPS IS ANY USEFUL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! E S P E C I A L L Y   N O T   F O R   M A T U R E   P E O P L E

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DWinLock](http://www.dwinlock.kassl.de/) we use it to do what you are asking for in one of our Delphi applications but it comes as a DLL and driver so should be able to be used in almost any programming language.

In our case its used to disable all the windows shortcuts and CTRL-ALT-DELETE while our system in running and restores that all back when it is correctly shut down, once the DLL is imported its easy to use.

```
Procedure DisableKeys;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('Disabling Keys - now secure'));
  wlDisableKey( 0, 0, MOD_WIN, 1 );
  wlDisableKey(0, VK_DELETE, MOD_CONTROL or MOD_ALT, 1);
  wlDisableKey( 0, VK_ESCAPE, MOD_CONTROL, 1 );
  wlDisableKey( 0, VK_ESCAPE, MOD_CONTROL or MOD_SHIFT, 1 );
  wlDisableKey( 0, VK_APPS, MOD_ALL, 1 );
  wlDisableKey( 0, VK_F4, MOD_ALT, 1 );
  wlDisableKey( 0, VK_F3, MOD_ALL, 1 );
  wlDisableKey( 0, ord('N'), MOD_CONTROL, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccessibility, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccHighContrast, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccFilterKeys, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccMouseKey, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccStickyKeys, 1 );
  wlDisableItem( wlAccToggleKeys, 1 );
end;

procedure EnableKeys;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('EnablingKeys - NOT secure'));
  wlRestoreAll;
end;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Fine for a kiosk app, not remotely fine for a general-purpose PC.

Comment: wow...thanks man..finally some hope.
You just shuted everyones mouth here with your answer.

Comment: @ Martin, I agree ours isn't a kiosk app but similarly needs to be protected.

Answer (score 0):

In web application you can limit user input with a fairly simple javascript, but you cant restrict browser. In desktop app you can use windows hooks etc. only problem is that all major antivirus software will think of your app as a threat. Not impossible, if you want it badly enaugh you could start by researching simple marc 3 keyloggers. Good luck.